# Faster ways of console I/O in C#

Tags: c#, io, console

I recently started using C# on programming contest sites like sphere online judge. One thing I noticed is, that Console I/O can really slow down my programs in C#.

I am mainly using Console.ReadLine and Console.WriteLine methods. For the integer parsing I have written my own parser, because the built in parsers are [quite slow](http://blogs.davelozinski.com/curiousconsultant/csharp-net-fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int)

I am aware, that writing to console is slow, so when there is a lot to be written, I use StringBuilder to build up all the output and write all of them once using a single Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()) call.

Are there any more optimizations I could to to fasten I/O? Are there any other ways of I/O than what I mentioned above?

(Please spare the *you-should-check-your-algorithm-first* kind of replies, this question is specifically about fast I/O. Thanks for understanding.)

Comment: Update the console from a threadpool thread perhaps: `Task.Run(()=> Console.WriteLine(string););`

Comment: String concatenation or StringBuilder is a minor issue here. Console is slow and will stay slow. If feasible, use a file for the big output

Comment: What I can't catch is how can be performance sensitive...something that READS from console and write back to it. If you need such fast I/O then user won't even see what you're doing. If output will be redirected to file then you may consider to make it asynchronous (all I/O in one thread but with a non blocking queue).

Comment: @user574632 no, console isn't thread-safe (you can write from another thread but you can't parallelize writings).

Comment: @user574632 what would change "delegating the IO to the thread pool", Console IO is still slow. Now you will have many threads waiting to output.

Comment: Seems i have misunderstood the problem then, please disregard

Comment: Side note: do you trust a benchmark like that (comparison of Convert.ToInt32/Int32.Parse/int.Parse)? Seriously?! Obviously if you skip all error checking and culture aware stuff then your code will be faster. You can compare with Int32.Parse (exactly the same as Int.Parse) and ignore Convert (because it does even more stuff).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti As I have written I need fast I/O for programming contest sites. These redirect the input and output to files, and they measure the runtime of the program. In a lot of these challanges a millions of lines needs to be written/read. Yes error checking is unnecessary in these problems, thats why I write my own parsers.

Comment: The only sensible answer is to eliminate I/O from the measured parts. Any contest/benchmark that does not separate the I/O out seems flawed.

Comment: If you're at such fine tuning then I have 3 tips: 1) **pool StringBuilder** (performance gain will be GREAT). 2) **Write in another thread** (simply enqueue to a non-blocking queue that will _wake-up_ thread delegated to writing). 3) As very last resource avoid Console.Write() and go directly with a StreamWriter on standard output (it'll manage buffering for you too).

Comment: @HenkHolterman They cant seperate it, since you have to write a complete program, and the runtime of that entire program is measured which includes reading and writing of the data.

Comment: This sounds like a question that belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not SO.

Comment: @VSZM LOL that is ridiculous, sorry. What happens if their freaking hard drive explodes precisely in the moment it's running your application? do you lose the freaking contest due to a circumstantial issue which is completely out of your control? that's nothing but stupid. There are so many factors that could affect I/O speed that it's just impossible to measure in a multi-tasking environment such as a web server or the like.

Answer (score 2):

I am speeding up Console I/O in this way:

Parsing long arrays

```
static IEnumerable<T> ReadArray<T>(string arrayLine, Func<string, T> parseFunction, char separator = ' ')
{
    int from = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLine.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrayLine[i] == separator)
        {
            yield return parseFunction(arrayLine.Substring(from, i - from));
            from = i + 1;
        }
    }

    yield return parseFunction(arrayLine.Substring(from));
}
```

and you can use the method this way

```
var array = ReadArray(Console.ReadLine(), s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

you can gain extra miliseconds avoiding ToArray() call and returning the array directly as most of the time array length is part of input.

Print efficiently (Some time it is not enough)

```
class Program
{
    static StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());

    internal static void Run()
    {
        int testCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int t = 0; t < testCount; t++)
        {
            // Do your logic here. For example
            var result = FooBarSolution(...);
            output.WriteLine(result);               
        }
        output.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the GIST.

Reading as a string and converting it back as integer or long etc., has unwanted overhead.

Things to think through:

1. Can you read multiple test cases in a single go?
2. Can you read the inputs in a format that is supported and easier to convert to other datatypes? [String is just simple for developers ;)]
3. Can you read it in a buffered way?
4. Unsafe code is supported by SPOJ C# compiler? Then you can save bit more ticks? so on..,

Here is my take on INOUT test

You should use a huge buffer (byte[]) and read all console input as bytes - then loop through that using ReadByte() till you see a whitespace character and convert that segment as integer or long or string as per your input format.

It is quite effective and has saved lot of time for problems with strict time limits.

Here is my sample code

```
public int ReadInt()
    {
        byte readByte;
        while ((readByte = GetByte()) < '-') ;

        var neg = false;
        if (readByte == '-')
        {
            neg = true;
            readByte = GetByte();
        }
        var m = readByte - '0';
        while (true)
        {
            readByte = GetByte();
            if (readByte < '0') break;
            m = m * 10 + (readByte - '0');
        }
        return neg ? -m : m;
    }
```

This is my code used in SPOJ
https://github.com/davidsekar/C-sharp-Programming-IO/blob/master/ConsoleInOut/InputOutput.cs

Thanks,

[davidsekar](https://davidsekar.com)

Comment: How useful is BufferedStream in your V3? Any drawbacks?

Comment: @MikhailOrlov BufferedStream is not that fast, probably due to additional checks it does internally. InputOutputV2 is still the fastest

Comment: Based on this rank https://www.spoj.com/ranks/INOUTEST/lang=cs